# html2canvas running before $modalInstance can close

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, html2canvas

I'm currently implementing a feedback modal in my Angular app that uses [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to take a "screenshot" of the users current page.  However, the `html2canvas` function is executing before my `$modalInstance` closes.  Essentially I want to capture what's "underneath" my modal window.

My logic is probably too simple:

```
app.controller('feedbackCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.feedback = {
    choice: null
  };

  // Promise that $modalInstance is finished
  $modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    if($scope.feedback.choice) {
      var target = $('body');
      html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var img = canvas.toDataURL();
          window.open(img);
        }
      });      
    }
  });

  angular.extend($scope, {
    ok: function () {
      $modalInstance.close();    
    },
    cancel: function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestions on how to ensure my `$modalInstance` completes its execution before `html2canvas()` fires off?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please guide me how to refer to html2canvas in your angular project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem in a hackish way with jQuery by simply removing the modal window from the DOM before calling `html2canvas()`:

```
$modalInstance.result.then(function() {
  if($scope.feedback.choice) {
    $('.modal-content').remove(); // Removes the modal from the DOM
    var target = $('body');
    html2canvas(target, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
        window.open(img);
      }
    });      
  }
});
```

I'm not thrilled with this solution, but it works for now.